# vertical align not working in div

Tags: css, html

i am trying to texbox over to button but my case first line texbox then next line in button 
html:-

```
 <div class="styled-input" id="surnamediv">
                                <input type="text" id="surName" /><button id="add" class="hidden">Add</button>
                                <label>Surname</label>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
```

css:-

```
.custom-input #surnamediv #add{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: There's not even a question here. What happened, what you expect to happen? Where is the reproduction?

Comment: Its coming in one line only for me. Can you replicate it on some fiddle, so that I can look into it

Comment: There is no css class called ".custom-input". Did you mean "styled-input"?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma thanks madam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these styles

```
#surnamediv {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
#surnamediv label {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```css
#surnamediv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#surnamediv label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-input" id="surnamediv">
  <input type="text" id="surName" /><button id="add" class="hidden">Add</button>
  <label>Surname</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Vertical-align work with flex*

```
<style>
    .styled-input {
    width:100℅;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#surnamediv {
  display: table;
}

#surnamediv input,
#surnamediv button,
#surnamediv label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#surnamediv label {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-input" id="surnamediv">
  <input type="text" id="surName" /><button id="add" class="hidden">Add</button>
  <label>Surname</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```